# Constraining a function argument in an interface

Tags: idris

What is the syntax to constrain a function argument in an interface which takes a function? I tried:

```
interface Num a => Color (f : a -> Type) where
     defs...
```

But it says the `Name a is not bound in interface...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `interface` actually has two parameters: `a` and `f`. But `f` should be enough to pick an `implementation`:

```
interface Num a => Color (a : Type) (f : a -> Type) | f where
```

`f` here is called a [*determining parameter*](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#determining-parameters).

Here's a nonsensical full example:

```
import Data.Fin

interface Num a => Color (a : Type) (f : a -> Type) | f where
  foo : (x : a) -> f (1 + x)

Color Nat Fin where
  foo _ = FZ

x : Fin 6
x = foo {f = Fin} 5
```

Comment: Ooo I had the two parameter interface but I didn't realize I can use `| f` to force just one to decide, this is excellent.